# Laravel model with append function and passing parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I'm having a &*^% of a time with this one. I've done some digging and I just can't seem to find the correct (or possible) way to accomplish what I'm looking for.

*A bit of backstory. I've written this query to integrate directly with nv3d graph library, hence why the data structure is so important to me as well as scoping the date correctly.*

First we have a model query for "Products", this creates me a nice ordered list with id, title and color.

```
Product::whereCuId(auth()->user()->cu_id)
        ->whereCategoryId($id)
        ->orderBy('sort_order', 'ASC')
        ->select('id as id','title AS key', 'color AS color')
        ->get();
```

Which returns me the following.

```
{
"id": 1,
"key": "Title 1",
"color": "#ffbd13",
}
{
"id": 2,
"key": "Title 2",
"color": "#8f8f8f"
}
(etc)
```

Step one: Great!

Next inside the Product model I am appending dates/values to each product. This is where the issue exists.

How is it possible to pass parameters to this secondary query like a date count, range, etc?!

```
protected $appends = array('values');
    public function getValuesAttribute() {
        return $values=Checkin::whereProductId($this->id)
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->whereRaw('Date(created_at) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 day')
            ->get(array(
                DB::raw('1000*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(created_at)) as date'),
                DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total')
            ));
    }
```

Now obviously I can use something like this which is currently in the above query....

```
->whereRaw('Date(created_at) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 day')
```

But how is it possible for me to pass parameters from the initial controller (that calls the product model) into the sub function inside the model and say... set the above "21" to a variable I pass in?

Thank you all in advance for the help!!!

This is the end goal of the data format and as it currently exists (without being able to change the range of days) just included as an example.

```
{
"id": 1,
"key": "Title 1",
"color": "#ffbd13",
"values": [
  {
  "date": 1468047600000,
  "total": 4
  },
  {
  "date": 1468134000000,
  "total": 1
  },
  {
  "date": 1468220400000,
  "total": 1
  },
  {
  "date": 1468306800000,
  "total": 2
  }]
}
{
"id": 2,
"key": "Title 2",
"color": "#8f8f8f"
}
(etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for closure. Didn't test it, but should give you the idea:

```
$yourVar = 21;
$values=Checkin::whereProductId($this->id)
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($yourVar) {
            $query->whereRaw('Date(created_at) > CURDATE() - INTERVAL '.$yourVar.' day'));
        })
        ->get(array(
            DB::raw('1000*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(created_at)) as date'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(id) as total')
        ));
```

Comment: I still don't understand how I can pass that value of 21 (or any value) from the previous Product:: query through to that specific function, that's my real issue here.  Thank you though!